# How to run a shell script within another shell script on a different server?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I created a shell script (Script 1) that I need to execute in server A; using Script 1, I need to execute another shell script (Script 2) that resides in Server B.

I am able to do so with the following line:

```
result=$(ssh ServerB /path/to/script/Script2.sh 2020-01-01 2020-03-12)
```

The problem is that Script 2, which I do not have edit access, calls another shell script using ./Script3 , I am getting an error stating

```
"./Script3 : Not found"
```

I believe the reason behind that is that it is looking for ./Script3 within Server A, rather than looking for it in Server B

How should I execute script 1 to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's looking for it on Server B. But it's looking for it in your current directory, which is your home directory. The script is probably in `/path/to/script`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looking for it in the `.` directory on Server B. Since you didn't change directory, the current directory is your home directory, not the directory containing the scripts. Either change `Script2.sh` to use the full path to `Script3` instead of `./Script3`, or you should change to the directory containing the scripts before running them.

```
result=$(ssh ServerB 'cd /path/to/script; ./Script2.sh 2020-01-01 2020-03-12')
```